# Two admin modules design showing same page?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created two different modules (app->code->local->1) Mca, 2) Mba & design-> adminhtml->default->Course->layout-> 1) mca.xml 2) mba.xml) and its working fine to accessing front end modules. When I go to back end modules they are showing different menus but In Mca module displaying both modules (mca & mba) design, but to accessing Mba module displaying empty page. I don’t’ know why displaying both modules in same page, but I give separate actions for both.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have the same layout handle for both of your modules `<adminhtml_controller_action>`.
You should move admin controllers in a subfolder with the module name and change the layout handles.
For example in you first module put the controller in `Course/Mba/controllers/Adminhtml/Mba/IndexController.php` (the controller may have a different name).

The the url should be `admin/mba_index/index`.
Do the same for the second module and the url  should be `admin/mca_index/index/`

Comment: Can you look on this? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/custom-tab-is-not-showing-in-configuration